# How much spare space is needed in foot-shaped children's shoes?

Tags: pediatrics, feet

In Germany, most advice regarding children's footwear says that there should be space from 12mm to 17mm between foot length and shoe inner length. From googling aroung I found that this advice is also given in the English-speaking countries, and probably others.

[Here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/19424280.2020.1853826) is a paper of a study done in Japan. They researched correlation between foot deformations (mainly hallux valgus) and spare space in the shoes.

I think this study is flawed because they do not consider shoe shape. Look at the following picture from that study:

[image]

You can easily see that foot shape and shoe shape do not fit together; the toe box is almost symmetric (longest part in the middle, getting shorter to both sides), unlike the feet. This way, either

1. the outer toes fit inside well but at the same time, the inner toes (especially the large one) must be squeezed towards the middle where the toe box is longest, or
2. the inner toes fit inside well, but then there is a huge empty space in the middle and outer part of the toe box. Which might not deform feet but might make it hard to walk, possibly resulting in other issues (like stumbling more often or muscle tensions).

This picture doesn't say that the shown shoe belongs to the shown feet, but the fact that foot shape and toe box shape in most western shoes do not fit together* is evident, I think. I know feet can vary greatly in shape, but I know of no healthy foot type that has its longest extent in the middle. The longest extent is either on the inside (if large toe is longest) or close to it (if the toe next to the large one is longest).

(*there are exceptions usually circumscribed as "barefoot shoes" which are becoming more popular but still far from mainstream)

So, if you do a study with such shoes, it is clear that you need a lot of difference between inner shoe length (which is from heel to middle of toe box) and foot length to not deform your inner toes. The children with "too short" shoes are case 1, the children with "fitting" shoes are case 2. You basically compare two lengths that are not reasonably comparable.

In order to have comparable lengths, foot shape and shoe shape must align. Like e.g. this shoe (the toe box is much closer to a healthy foot shape):

[image]

Long story short: **Does anyone know a study or some other robust piece of knowledge that says what amount of spare space is needed in FOOT-SHAPED shoes to keep children's feet healthy?**

Comment: Not sure what I think of the linked study: the difference of hallux angle for outdoor fit is barely significant (p=0.05), the difference for indoor fit is not significant [should they have adjusted the data for multiple hypothesis testing because they are testing the same hallux  angles on two variables? Then all effects are gone]. Only barefoot seems to have a stronger impact on hallux angles. They also did not in any way show health problems associated with the different hallux angles, which would have been nice. Maybe I‘m a bit too sceptic though

Comment: The author also sells a book, a special footwear measuring device and socks which are supposed to help with hallux valgus (not based on evidence) on his website, but did not find it necessary to share any potential conflicts of interests for this paper…